# How to get values to row on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, api

Hi i try to get data from api and record it to dataframe but not work. how can i fix it?

edit. i fetch data by ccxt lib to create order to exchange.

data info on buy

> ###create_buy_order : {'info': {'avgFillPrice': None, 'clientId': None, 'createdAt': '2020-11-19T13:30:25.969907+00:00', 'filledSize': 0.0, 'future': None, 'id': 14955364871, 'ioc': False, 'liquidation': False, 'market': 'ETHBEAR/USD', 'postOnly': False, 'price': 0.02378, 'reduceOnly': False, 'remainingSize': 10.0, 'side': 'buy', 'size': 10.0, 'status': 'new', 'type': 'limit'}
> # , 'id': '14955364871', 'clientOrderId': None, 'timestamp': 1605792625969, 'datetime': '2020-11-19T13:30:25.969Z', 'lastTradeTimestamp': None, 'symbol': 'ETH

In csv file only have columnsn not get values on row.

```
import ccxt 
exchange = ccxt.ftx({'apiKey':api_key,'secret':secret})
file = 'record.csv'
df=pd.read_csv(file)
buy =exchange.create_order(symbols+'/USD','limit','buy',10,0.02200)
buy_id= buy['info']['id']
buy_price= buy['info']['price']
buy_amount= buy['amount']

print(buy)
df['buy_id'] =  df.append(buy_id)## not working to append data on csv
df['buy_price'] = df.append(buy_price)##
df['buy_amount'] buy['amount'] ##
```

how can i save  infomation on my order when i send order to  csv.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAkGQ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set order by yourself using double bracket

```
df = df[['buy_prince','buy_id','buy_amount','close_id','close_amount']]
```

or directly:

```
df[['buy_prince','buy_id','buy_amount','close_id','close_amount']].to_csv('path')
```